# Unable to install VirtualBox 4.2 on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, apt, virtualbox

I am trying to install VirualBox 4.2 on Ubuntu 12.10 but when this is the error I get:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-4.2 : Depends: libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.7.2) but it is not going 
 to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And if I try to run the command for dependencies, I get the message that its already installed.
I have 64-bit Ubuntu and trying to install 64-bit VirtualBox

The issue seems to be with the linux-headers as I have 3.5.0.21 where as its asking for 3.5.0.17

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: I get this: `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: linux-headers-3.5.0-17 linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic`

Comment: now try to reinstall virtualbox

Comment: it isn't getting installed in the first place

Comment: how about downloading the deb file from its site? have you tried it?

Comment: yes i did that and it gets partially installed with error messages. This is what i get if i run the `install -f` command: `The following packages will be REMOVED: virtualbox-4.2
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
`